# ggplot legend list is larger than page

Tags: r, ggplot2, adobe-illustrator

I have a plot in R which has a very large number of sample groups, and therefore the legend is larger than the page size and is cut off.  I understand that this is not publication quality, but I need to know the colours to be able to make the legend in Illustrator.

Is there a way to make the page size much bigger or somehow change the legend format so that I can include all the keys?  The reason for this is so that I can open the PDF in Illustrator and get the colours for each sample to create a new legend that will be for publication.  I thought that maybe there is a clipping mask, and that the actual legend will be preserved, but when I opened in Illustrator, the legend was actually cut at the page ends1.

[image: Here is one exmple where the legend goes beyond the graph and the page size and is therefore cut off.]

As was suggested in the comments below I gave nrow a try which helped break the legends up but now the entire page is just legends.

```
ggplot(purine.n, aes(x=variable, y=value, colour=metabolite_gene, shape=variable))
+geom_abline(slope=0)
+geom_point(size=4, position=position_dodge(width=0.08))
+scale_y_continuous(limit=c(-3.5,5.5), breaks=c(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5))
+scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,17,17), guide=F)
+theme_bw()
+theme(legend.key=element_blank(), legend.key.size=unit(1,"point"))
+guides(colour=guide_legend(nrow=16))
```

Comment: Does using the [`nrow or ncol`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/guide_legend.html) argument help?  (imo  (fwiw) having this many factors / colours is not going to produce a very informative plot / legend)

Comment: Do you need to have a different color for each category?  Unless the categories are ordinal, this could be very hard for someone to read effectively. You may want to figure out a different way of differentiating categories.

Comment: Thanks, that led to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621920/guide-legend-and-ggplot2-format-nrow but unfortunately it did not resolve the issue.  I think what you pointed out is the right track tho! I've updated the question to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: @user1362215 I do need the colours as I use the colours to seperate out subcategories within the sample.  Actually, that will be the next thing I need to figure out is how to get category A and it's subcategories one shade of colour, B and it's subcategories another, and so on so forth.

Comment: @user20650 nrows worked but now I have a different problem.  The entire page is just legends >.<

Comment: @kennethPhough, ggplot is kind of bad when it comes to non-intuitive color schemes.  You can use `scale_color_manual`, aided with some color-handling functions, to work with them.  `hsv2col` and `col2hsv` might be useful in this case.

Comment: @user1362215 Ok, thanks for the advice! I'll definitely give that a try.

Comment: @user20650 Yes, thank you! The rnow attribute worked!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As was suggested in the comments, `nrow` was the answer to my problem.  I had to adjust the value to get the right number of rows to fit my legend.  Below is the completed code that worked.  There's more tweaking I need to do, like change page size to help make things look better, but that is out of the scope of this question.

```
ggplot(data.n, aes(x=variable, y=value, colour=metabolite_gene, shape=variable))
+geom_abline(slope=0)+geom_point(size=4, position=position_dodge(width=0.08))
+scale_y_continuous(limit=c(-3.5,5.5), breaks=c(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5))
+scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,17,17), guide=F)
+theme_bw()
+theme(legend.key=element_blank(), legend.key.size=unit(1,"point"))
+guides(colour=guide_legend(nrow=30))
```

[image: fixed legend with nrow]

Comment: Does this also work when you have guides for color and shape? I like to have a line for each (so instead of your 30, I would only need 2 - but cannot figure out how to do this.)